# Avoid DB Session addition marshmallow object while using marshmallow sql-alchemy object

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

Is there a way to avoid inserting the data into session while using Marshmallow - sqlalchemy

sqlalchemy marshmallow avoid loading into session

Ref: https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Because we tried to manage the objects by ourself. Will add into the session if required, but for validation I need to use `load()`

```
author = Author(name='Chuck Paluhniuk')
book = Book(title='Fight Club', author=author)
session.add(author)
session.add(book)
session.commit()

author_schema.dump(author).data
# {'books': [123], 'id': 321, 'name': 'Chuck Paluhniuk'}

author_schema.load(dump_data, session=session).data
# <Author(name='Chuck Paluhniuk')>
```

The work around to avoid this issue, after I tried with load I can call DB `Session.close()` to ignore the temporary data. But again I need to get the session to flush the data into DB .

Comment: The session this example refers to is not the Flask client side session implementation. The session this example refers to is the Flask app's session with its database.

Comment: Yes @Snuggert You are correct. I just gave example. I am fine passing session to marshmallow sqlalchemy . The only problem is while using .loads() after validation it  puts data into Session . Note : Marshmallow-sqlalchemy must requires session convert from DB model to Marshmallow Model.

Comment: @Shankar Have you considered using `marshmallow` without the SQLAlchemy integration?

Comment: @mam8cc Yes , We are using marshmallow and sqlalchemy sperately in our  project. I am looking for ways to integrate those as we need to define separate model for  DB & REST services.

Comment: @Shankar so you want a way to represent your data in the database but have a different representation marshalled from your API?

Comment: @mam8cc No, Mostly whatever the data in the database and marshalled data will be same . I can use marshmallow-sqlalchemy also in my project . But the problem is while validating the data in my POST request (Eg: author_schema.load(data, session=session).data results in dumping data into DB session. I don't want that behaviour because I do processing the data after validation , finally, I will do session.add(author),  session.commit() . Please suggest me if you know any way to avoid data managed by SQL session while  using .loads/load method overwritten by marshmallow-sqlalchemy

Answer (score -1):

The call to the schema's `load()` doesn't automatically add the object to the session:

```
>>> from models import session
>>> from schema import author_schema
>>> a = {'id': 1, 'name': 'Chuck Paluhniuk'}
>>> obj = author_schema.load(a, session=session)
>>> session.new
IdentitySet([])
>>> session.add(obj.data)
>>> session.new
IdentitySet([<Author(name=u'Chuck Paluhniuk')>])
>>> session.commit()
>>> session.new
IdentitySet([])
>>> session.identity_map.items()
[((<class 'models.Author'>, (1,)), <Author(name=u'Chuck Paluhniuk')>)]
>>> session.dirty
IdentitySet([])
```

The object must be making it into the session another way. Perhaps you could post some of your code exhibiting the issue?

**Update**: I added the output of `session.dirty` to my sample code. As you can see, it's empty. The claim is that `load()` changes the session, but it doesn't. Some other code does. Can you provide an example of the code that shows your scenario?

Comment: you may want to check the `session.dirty` and you'll see the object there. also you can just change some attributes and without adding the object to session execute `session.commit()` and you'll see that it will be flushed to the db

Comment: @mehdy Yes mehdy is rite.  My code sample will be more equivalent to the sample in documentation . I don't want schema.load() to load the data into DB  Session . I mentioned the reason in mehdy's answer comments. Please add your suggestions for this

Answer (score -1):

Adding the object  to the `session` has **no bad effect** on your code. As you said you're gonna do it yourself later. So there is no differences between adding it manually or by `load` method.

```
author = author_schema.load(dump_data, session=session)
# now author has been added to session by load method
# do whatever you want
db.session.commit() # This is enough to write changes you've made
# or if you don't want to save anything just
db.session.rollback()
```

I really didn't get why you want to prevent adding the object to the session by `load`'s method

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Even we can use db.session.close() to remove the objects from session I don't want an work around. Adding the object into session has an effect , I will try to explain. The difference is I am using load method only for Validation if there is an issue we will throw the error to user. Objects contains partial data , say I need to post the data to third party services only if it succeeds I need to put the data into DB. otherwise,  I can raise an error . I don't want load() method put the data into session. Please add your thoughts and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: as I see in case of valid data you're okay. and if the data are invalid you just can simply discard the object in session by calling `session.rollback()` and using rollback method is not a bad option. and even if it's a http API the session is a fresh one for every request. so nothing bad will happen even if you don't do anything with the data in session

Comment: Yes you are correct , say as I am implementing this I know the details , if  a new developer misses the session.rollback() / db.session.close ()in the new API then  bad data will be in the DB because of auto commit at the end . Am I correct ? I am seeing this is more error prone . Please advice

Comment: hmmm. yes it could happen. you may want to provide a function or even a decorator for validation that will be used for every validation and it will automatically clear the session in case of invalid data. but you can never prevent mistakes for 100% sure.

Comment: Yes that's true . Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I also had the same solution in my mind , I can provide that decorator , But I think the problem I tried to solve was simple, Avoiding duplicate schema (DB & REST marshmallow schema) . It will result in lot of complications. For now I am not going to add the decorator , as this solution requires two session and not straight forward . Instead maintaining two schemas for every API, Please suggest me if you have any other solution

Comment: I think it would better to stick to the idea of merging them and taking care of the session. I don't think you could find any better solution than duplicate schema for now

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help .

Comment: you're welcome :) you may select the answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Other suggestion I have for this problem is to create methods for save() delete() update(), where session is fresh and only performs operations on manually added objects in the session.